# URL formatting is broken in Marketing Cloud Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, url, formatting, data-import

We have noticed that since the latest release (08/10/2023) that Marketing Cloud has reformatted all URLs present in data extensions.

Formerly, they worked - we often use links in data extensions to populate email content (eg personalised links from other systems, ampscript lookup tables to retrieve specific links etc).

It seems to affect all types of import - I've tried uploading correctly written links manually to a data extension, and it changes all the formatting to HTML markup - eg `'and'` becomes `&amp;`, etc.

It has even changed older data extensions which used to be written correctly into this format.
As an example I just uploaded a CSV containing URLs:

[image]

And in the data extension, they look like this:

[image]

Does anyone know why this has suddenly started happening? It has made a vast amount of our data utterly useless and a lot of our automated emails will now fail.

Comment: this is a UI issue, it hasn't changed the underlying data.  https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000xazqYAAQ/~

Comment: @EazyE - good find. Can you place it in an answer, for increased visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a UI issue list here

[Special Characters in Data Extension being displayed with HEX value in UI on Email Studio](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000xazqYAAQ/%7E)

> Currently, there is no workaround available to visualise in Email Studio.
>
> However, this does not impact the usage of these values in Email, Export etc. Additionally, accessing the Data Extension through Contact Builder will render correctly and not display the HEX value.